# MySQL - is there a way to discard records in a sorted select after a given criteria is satisfied?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm working with a sorted data set like this:

```
ID    Test
----------
1      Y
2      Y
3      Y
4      N
5      Y
6      N
7      N
8      Y
```

I want to grab all rows that are `Test = Y` and have an `ID` that is  **LESS** than the first occurrence (if existing) of the `ID` tied to the row of the first instance of `Test = N`.

So I'd like a query that just returned:

```
ID    Test
----------
1      Y
2      Y
3      Y
```

I know I could layer sub selects and I might have to do that, but I was just curious if there was any more clever way to achieve this in Mysql 5.7+.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I don't understand `and have an ID that is greater than the first occurrence (if existing) of the ID tied to the row of the first instance of Test = N`

Comment: I'm not sure of a "move clever" way.  Often (most?) times, selecting data is done in layers: get this, join with that, select from the result, add something else, get the final set.  It's normal (although best optimizing things can be interesting at times, but in general theory...)

Comment: @AaronDietz: especially when the example showed only rows where the ID is smaller than the first ID for `test = N`

Comment: @AaronDietz, my apologies, I meant "Less".  I've updated the question to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable
WHERE 
    CASE 
       WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM YourTable WHERE Test = 'N')
         THEN (id < (SELECT MIN(id) FROM YourTable WHERE Test = 'N') AND Test = 'Y')
         ELSE Test = 'Y'
       END;
```